# angular-fullstack directive causes Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I've got an angular-fullstack project that I've been working on. Everything has been working fine, until I tried to make a directive. At first I thought my directive was too complex, but I've since tried with a stock, generated directive and I'm still getting the same error.

Directive is here:

```
 'use strict';

 angular.module('angularApp')
      .directive('test', function () {
        return {
          templateUrl: 'app/test/test.html',
          restrict: 'EA',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          }
        };
      });
```

I inject it here in main.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, socket, characterService, test) {
    $scope.path = new Array();
    $scope.heroes = new Array();

    characterService.all().success(function(data) {
      $scope.heroes = data;
    });

  });
```

Everything works fine as long as I don't have test in the list of injected stuff, but if it's there, I get the error.

angular.js:11607Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testProvider <- test <- MainCtrl

Is there somewhere else I need to add it? I've tried adding it to the dependency list like this:

```
angular.module('angularApp')
      .controller('MainCtrl', ['test', function ($scope, $http, socket, characterService, test)
    ...
```

But that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would be the point of injecting a directive in a ... controller?

It strictly makes no sense, since directive aims to build a new HTML attribute/markup:

```
<test></test>
```

for instance.

Besides, a directive **can** define/use a controller in its implementation.
Don't confuse the whole ;)

Comment: I probably should've read more of the documentation before diving in. Thanks for the help!